# Problems in checking for occurence of each character in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, nested-loops

I am trying to make a program that counts the occurence of *each* character in a string, like this:

```
Enter string: hello world
```

With the output being

```
h: 1
e: 1
l: 3
o: 2
```

...and so on

But my output seems all over the place, like:

```
Enter string: nice on ice
n: 2
i: 2
c: 1
e: 1 //there should be 2 e's
o: 1
```

and sometimes like:

```
Enter string: potato
p: 1
o: 2
t: 2
a: 1

: 1
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char l, str[30], cpy[30];
  int i, j, occ;
  i = j = 0;
  occ = 0;
  cout << "Enter string: ";
  fgets(str, 10, stdin);
  strcpy(cpy, str); // copy the string as I am about to modify it

  // Checks for occurences of each character.
  // Every character found is changed to a ' ' so that it isn't counted again
  while (str[i] != '\0') {

    occ = 0;
    if (str[i] != ' ') {

      l = str[i];
      for (j = 0; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {

        if (str[j] == cpy[i] && str[j] != ' ') {
          occ++;
          str[j] = ' ';
        }

      }
      cout << l << ": " << occ <<endl;
    }
    i++;
  }

  cout << "\n";
  fputs(str, stdout); // just to check if all characters were converted to ' '
  cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://onlinegdb.com

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Is there a reason you mix C++ and C input and output? Is this an assignment that you have to do this yourself, and not rely on e.g. `std::map`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll admit, that I have to catch up with many changes, because I'm being taught C++98 in a DOS emulator. Although this is not homework, I attempted this for some practice with character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to make a copy, and your inner loop is doing too much work, iterating over characters that have already been invalidated.  Plus, you seem to be getting confused about whether the copy or the original is indexed by `i` or `j`.

```
int main()
{
    char str[30];
    int i, j, occ;

    cout << "Enter string: ";
    fgets(str, 10, stdin);

    // Checks for occurences of each character.
    // Every character found is changed to a ' ' so that it isn't counted again
    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
        {
            // Output the current character before it is invalidated.
            cout << str[i] << ": ";

            // Start at the current character so that it is counted
            // at least once.
            occ = 0;
            for (j = i; str[j] != '\0'; j++)
            {
                // No need to test for ' ', because str[i] is not
                // a ' ', so equality is sufficient.
                if (str[j] == str[i])
                {
                    occ++;
                    // Invalidate each counted character.
                    str[j] = ' ';
                }
            }
            cout << occ << endl;
        }
    }

    // just to check if all characters were converted to ' '
    cout << endl << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, but the new output is still off. It is now repeating characters to be counted, and also over-counting, which is strange, because I tried dry-running your code, and it seemed to be correct...

Answer (score 0):

For a possible solution to your assignment, remember that there are 26 letters in the English alphabet, and it's simple to translate each letter into an index into an array (with [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) it is *extremely* simple).

Armed with this information think about having an array of 26 integers, where each element in the array is a counter of the characters you read.

So just read a single character at a time in a loop, get the counter-array index from the character, and increase the correct element. No need to actually store the text you read, no need for multiple loops of checks.

When printing, loop over the array and print every element that is non-zero, together with its corresponding character.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, but an interesting alternative nonetheless. I'll look into it!